# Need the output of a chunk but need to put eval = FALSE to render in Quarto with R

Tags: html, r, rstudio, quarto

I'm trying to render a quarto document to a HTML page with GitHub R Studio. The code include several plots and a single DT table as show in the following code, however in order to render without errors I need to use `#| eval: false` which by default doesn't allow the table to show in the final HTML page and I need the table to show.

I think it might be a problem with `{dplyr}`, but I've remove and reinstall the packages several times and it's not working.

```
#| label: tabla-felino
#| eval: false

x |>
 select(a,b,c) |>
 datatable(options = list(
   pageLength = 5,
   language = list(url = '//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.11/i18n/Spanish.json')))
```

---

The error I get is:

> Quitting from lines 169-181 (index.qmd)
> Error in crosstalk::is.SharedData(data) :
> objeto 'x' no encontrado
> Calls: .main ... eval_with_user_handlers -> eval -> eval -> datatable ->

However, the object x is properly in the environment.

I've tried using

```
 #| output: true
 #| include: true
 #| echo: true
 #| eval: false
```

But, as eval do not show the output it doesn't work.

I truly appreciate the help, thanks!

Comment: How have you verfied that `x` is initalized? Quarto render starts a new clean environment, it doesn't have access to objects in your current RStudio session. So if your current ducument does not explicitly set `x`  or only sets in some `eval: false` block, it's unknown for Quarto.